# Jasmine, can't initialize

Tags: javascript, ruby, jasmine

I have a ruby-javascript project without any rails, merb and etc frameworks. Gem successfully installed but when I tried to initialize jasmine `jasmine init` I've got this message:

```
can't activate rack (~> 1.2.1, runtime) for ["actionpack-3.0.3", "railties-3.0.3"], 
already activated rack-1.3.0 for ["jasmine-1.0.2.1]
```

Gemfile:

```
source "http://rubygems.org"
gem "coderay"
gem 'ruby-debug19'
gem 'jasmine'
```

How to fix this problem? Thanks

P.S. Windows 7, DivKit

P.S.1. Seems that `bundle exec jasmine init` should work but I've got another error:

```
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jasmine-1.0.2.1/lib/jasmine/tasks/jasmine.rake:1:
  in `<top (required)>': undefined method `namespace' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
from e:/Work/ReadTheCode/Rakefile:4:in `load'
from e:/Work/ReadTheCode/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jasmine-1.0.2.1/lib/jasmine
                                                /command_line_tool.rb:49:in `load'
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jasmine-1.0.2.1/lib/jasmine
                                                /command_line_tool.rb:49:in `process'
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jasmine-1.0.2.1/bin/jasmine
                                                :6:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin/jasmine:19:in `load'
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin/jasmine:19:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your rails installation depend on rack 1.3.0 in the root Gemfile, or try to make jasmine depend on rack 1.2.1